# Shopify Sections Get Removed On Pushing Theme From Local To Live Store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Sections get removed when pushing a theme from local to live store using the "shopify theme push" command .I am using Dawn theme version "12.0.0" and Shopify CLI version "3.52.0" . I need to add every section in the page everytime after pushing local to live store.

I expect I don't have to add every section on the page once I saved it. After saving the page all sections on that page should retain as long as I remove them manually but in my case all sections are automatically getting removed from the page after everytime I push shopify theme from local to live store.

Please check the below images for better understanding:

1. [Image of Sections added to page Before push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2es9.png)

2 .[Image of Sections automaticaly removed after push](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP34o.png)

I checked files like settings_schema.json and other configuration files related to sections but I did not find any error.

Answer (score 0):

When you push the local file, you are resetting the live theme settings of sections. You need to pull a live theme before pushing it on live again to update the settings on your local machine. So, basically, you are updating the JSON file that contains the data about the pages and their sections.

The command may vary depending on the version of Shopify CLI; in your case, it should be like so:

```
shopify theme pull
```

You can use GitHub integration to avoid this behavior. It helps you to store the theme files in one place and update only those you have changed. And great to work with a team.